# VBA - https response text decryption

Tags: vba, ssl, certificate

In VBA, I need to request http message and parse the response text.
I've succeeded to get the response text with http status '200', but the body is encrypted. (headers are not) So I have been trying to decrypt the message, but with poor knowledge of SSL concepts and programming skills, I've got stuck.

```
With oRequest
    .Open "GET", sUrl, False
    .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "*/*"
    .SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
    .SetRequestHeader "Connection", "Keep -Alive"
    '.SetClientCertificate ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/SystemCertificates/CA/Certificates")   
    .Send 
    sResult = .GetAllResponseHeaders
    Debug.Print sResult
    sResult = .ResponseText
    Debug.Print sResult
```

The script above is what I've written. With this, I have some questions.

**1. 'SetClientCertificate()' is necessary? How could I get the response text successfully?**

- As I've searched, 'SetClientCertificate()' is the method to send ssl message to server. However, I've sent (and gotten the response) a message successfully without the method. I can't understand how this works.

**2. In VBA, how to use certificate to decode the response body**

- I really have no idea about how to decrypt response text. I know that there's a proper certificate in my local computer and the key in the certificate can be used to decrypt the message, but how can I do this in VBA? I really could not find any helpful articles about this.

Please let me know what I misunderstand and give me any clues to solve the problem.

**[+ Editing]**

in the script, there was a line :

```
.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip , deflate"
```

I've omitted this line in the question. Because I had thought the issue is about SSL, so I intentionally removed some lines that are not really necessary as I guessed. (this was perfectly wrong)

With removing the line, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've succeeded to get the response text with http status '200', but the body is encrypted.

This does not make sense. In HTTPS everything is encrypted: request header and body and also response header and body. I rather expect that you get both the decrypted response header and body back but that the body is maybe compressed or in a format you don't recognize so that it looks like encryption for you.

> 'SetClientCertificate()' is necessary? How could I get the response text successfully?

This is needed if the server requires the client to authenticate itself with a client certificates. Most sites don't need this.

> In VBA, how to use certificate to decode the response body

You can't. And the body  you've got is probably not encrypted or at least not encrypted with anything relating to the TLS (HTTPS) connection (see above).

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was not about encryption but the compression as you mentioned. I  removed the line 
".SetRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip , deflate"
then it works. the line was not written in my original question (just I've mistaken in posting or editing).
Thanks. I think I should study more about this. Frankly I don't 100% understand what's going on.